# C# lambda - Differences (Except) of inner lists inside two lists

Tags: c#, lambda

I have two lists of 'Table' 1 ----N 'Columns.
The first list holds the default schema that must be achieved.
The second list holds the schema defined by the user.
I need to compare the second list against the first one, retrieving the tables where the schema mismatches, also the list of columns missing/unknown.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Table
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IList<Column> Columns {get;set;}
  public Table()
  {
    Columns = new List<Column>();
  }
}
public class Column
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
//...
var Default1 = new Table() { Name = "Table1" };
Default1.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "X1" });
Default1.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "X2" });
var Default2 = new Table() { Name = "Table2" };
Default2.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "Y1" });
Default2.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "Y2" });

var DefaultSchema = new List<Table>() { Default1, Default2 };

var T1 = new Table() { Name = "Table1" };
T1.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "X1" });
var T2 = new Table() { Name = "Table2" };
T2.Columns.Add(new Column() { Name = "Y2" });

var MyTables = new List<Table>() { T1, T2};

/*
var DiffTables = DefaultSchema.Join(??).Select(x => x.Columns).Except(?? MyTables.Select(y => y.Columns) ...
*/
```

Expected result:

```
var DiffTables =
 {
  {
    Name = "Table1",
    Columns =
    {
      Name = "X2" //Missing from DefaultSchema.Table1
    }
  },
  {
    Name = "Table2",
    Columns =
    {
      Name = "Y1" //Missing from DefaultSchema.Table2
    }
  }
 }
```

Is there any way of doing this with a lamdba expression, or just by a master+nested foreach?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the two lists guaranteed to be of the same size and contain the same table names in the correct order?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, No!, because the second schema is user-made!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparing just two tables, it would be:

```
Default1.Columns
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Except(T1.Columns.Select(x => x.Name));
```

For comparing two schemas, it would be:

```
DefaultSchema
    .Zip(MyTables, (x, y) => new
        { Name = x.Name,
          MissingColumns = x.Columns.Select(x1 => x1.Name)
              .Except(y.Columns.Select(y1 => y1.Name)) });
```

`Zip` combines any two sequences, so that item 1 gets matched with item 2, item 2 gets matched with item 2, etc. (in other words, like a zipper).

`Except` removes all items of one sequence from another sequence.

As @MetroSmurf pointed out, my original version had an error that was causing `Except` to fail. The reason is that the it was comparing the columns based on whether they are referring to the same object. I added the inner `Select` statements to allow the columns to be compared by `Name` instead.

Note also that this answer assumes the two schema being compared have the same tables in the same order.

---

Another way to go (inspired by @MetroSmurf's use of `IEquatable`) is to create a custom `IEqualityComparer`, like this:

```
public class ColumnComparer : IEqualityComparer<Column>
{
    public bool Equals(Column x, Column y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Column column)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(column, null)) return 0;
        return column.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then the LINQ query reduces down to just this:

```
DefaultSchema.Zip(MyTables, (x, y) => new
{
    Name = x.Name,
    MissingColumns = x.Columns.Except(y.Columns, new ColumnComparer())
});
```

Again, the same assumption that the tables are equivalent for the two schemas applies.

---

If this assumption doesn't apply (i.e., MyTables are not in order or may be missing tables), you can use a "left outer join" instead:

```
var result =
    from table in DefaultSchema
    join myTable in MyTables on table.Name equals myTable.Name into matchingTables
    from matchingTable in matchingTables.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        Name = table.Name,
        MissingColumns = matchingTable == null
            ? null
            : table.Columns.Except(matchingTable.Columns, new ColumnComparer())
    };
```

With this query, a result is generated for every table in `DefaultSchema`. If one or more of the `MyTables` has the same name, the missing columns get reported. If the table is missing from `MyTables`, the value of `MissingColumns` is `null`. Note that this will not report on any *extra* tables in `MyTables` that don't exist in `DefaultSchema`.

Comment: A. This does not compile. B. The result (if fixed to compile) will end up with "X1", "X2" in the first result and "Y1", "Y2" in the second result.

Comment: Well, the original post would not compile, but you've updated to project into an anonymous result which does compile :) (darn you, and now you deleted your comment **shakes fist**)  However, the results are still incorrect. I think using a linq solution here is really just over complicating what an easier to read and maintain loop could accomplish.

Comment: Good catch...Now it compares column names (instead of the whole object) when doing the `Except` operation.

Comment: Worked great... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
var result =
    DefaultSchema
        .Select(
            table =>
                new
                {
                    Table = table,
                    UserTable = MyTables.FirstOrDefault(utable => utable.Name == table.Name)
                })
        .Select(item => new
        {
            Name = item.Table.Name,
            MissingColumns =
                item.UserTable == null
                    ? item.Table.Columns.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()
                    : item.Table.Columns.Select(x => x.Name)
                        .Except(item.UserTable.Columns.Select(x => x.Name))
                        .ToArray()
        }).ToList();
```

This code handles the case where the two lists are not guaranteed to have the same number of tables or to have the tables in the correct order.

It starts by selecting the default schema table with its corresponding user table (or `null` of the user table is not found).

Then, for each such object, it creates a new object that contains the default schema table name, and the list of missing columns.

The list of missing columns are all the columns in the default schema table if a corresponding user table is not found.

If a corresponding user table is found, `Except` is used to subtract the list of columns defined in the user table from the columns defined in the default schema table.

Answer (score 1):

Using a complex Linq query is going to over-complicate what would be an otherwise easier to understand and maintainable loop. An alternative to devuxer's suggestion (which works great assuming everything in both lists can be zipped):

First, I'd implement IEquatable for an easy comparison:

```
public class Column : IEquatable<Column>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals( Column other )
    {
        // consider case insensitive comparison if needed.
        return Name == other.Name;
    }
}
```

The loop then becomes:

```
var diffs = new List<Table>();

foreach( Table table in MyTables )
{
    Table schema = DefaultSchema
        // consider case insensitive comparison if needed.
        .FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == table.Name );

    if( schema == null )
    {
        // no matching schema, everything should be evaluated.
        diffs.Add( table );
        continue;
    }

    // use IEquatable to pull out the differences
    List<Column> columns = table.Columns.Except( schema.Columns ).ToList();

    if( columns.Any() )
    {
        diffs.Add( new Table { Name = table.Name, Columns = columns } );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Your use of `IEquatable` here inspired me expand upon my answer again, but I took a slightly different approach. Instead of `IEquatable`, which permanently changes the rules for how `Column` objects are tested for equality, I went with an `IEqualityComparer`, which can be applied as needed to any LINQ query. Also, I think the preference for LINQ query vs. loop is highly subjective. If you are used to thinking in terms of LINQ queries (or functionally in general), it actually makes intent very clear to know that you are zipping, joining, etc. two sets of data.

Comment: @devuxer Totally agree with Linq v. loops. My preference is typically a Linq expression; over time and working with hundreds of developers, I've come to realize that there are just some times when a fancy Linq expression may look nice and tidy, but simply causes too many other developers to mis-understand the concepts. In this case, the OP went as far as saying the lists are not guaranteed to be the same size and zipping may have some unintended side effects. To be fair, though, I once wrote a Linq expression with 5+ inner group by clauses (yes, groups inside of groups).

Comment: @MetroSmurf, I think we're basically in agreement. It's definitely important to consider *who* will be maintaining the code. If those developers are not well versed in LINQ or functional programming, more complex LINQ queries might do more harm then good. Philosophically speaking, though, I do think LINQ result in code that is naturally more "self documenting" and expressive. The function names say a lot about what you are trying to do, and the efficient, terse syntax is a nice bonus.